# How to write JSON object in java code?

Tags: java, json

My `Json` are following

```
{
"q": {
      "region": "NYC",
      "or": [
         {
             "duration": "12"
         }
            ]
     },
"sort": "recent"
}
```

How to write in `JsonObject`.I tried with following code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj4 = new JSONObject();
  try {
      obj.put("q", obj1);
      obj.put("sort", "recent");

      obj1.put("reg", "NYC");
      obj2.put("duration", new Integer(12));
      obj4.put()
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
```

I got stuck in creating Array of list. How can I convert into Json Object?

Comment: You know there's a `JSONObject` type since you're using it. Do you think there might be a `JSONArray` type?

Comment: yes there is `JSONArray` type of class

Comment: Knowing that, where do you go from here?

Comment: That means I need to create `jsonArray` of `List` and add it to as `obj1.put("or", JsonArray)`. right?

Answer (score 0):

You may build the JSONObject in this way:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("q", new JSONObject()
                .put("region", "NYC")
                .put("or", new JSONArray()
                    .put(new JSONObject()
                        .put("duration","12"))))
            .put("sort", "recent");

        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

The output:
`{"q":{"or":[{"duration":"12"}],"region":"NYC"},"sort":"recent"}`